# QDialog crashes with QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog as true

Tags: qt, qt6

I basically want to implement a functoin to select either a folder or a file name with just one Qt File Dialog box, and here is my code:

```
class CustomFileDialog : public QFileDialog {
public:
    CustomFileDialog(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : 
QFileDialog(parent) {}
protected:
    void accept() override {
        done(Accepted); // Override the accept method to change the behavior
    }
};

CustomFileDialog dialog(nullptr);
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly, false);
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog, true);
```

It works ok in most cases, but it fails with an Access Violation error whenever I double click a folder with ".raw" files.

I am using Qt6 at Windows 11.

EDIT:
with more testing, I am able reproduce the problem with a standard file selecting object defined directly by "QFileDialog dialog(nullptr);", and I am also able to reproduce it without setting the QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog flag to be true. More interestingly, I create an empty text file and change its extension to .raw, and the code crashes whenever this file appears in the file selecting dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code according to [Qt Dcoument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html).

1.

> Options (particularly the DontUseNativeDialogs option) should be set before changing dialog properties or showing the dialog.

You should set option first.

2.

> QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog
>
> > Don't use the native file dialog. By default, the native file dialog is used unless you use a subclass of QFileDialog that contains the Q_OBJECT macro, or the platform does not have a native dialog of the type that you require.

You should add `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class.

Comment: Adjusting the order of setting dialog options works ok. I will keep watching to see if the problem comes back some how. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately the problem comes back, even I add Q_OBJECT in CustomFileDialog class. It seems the code somehow behaves unstable. If I set QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog to be false, the problem is gone, but I lose the functoinality of making the CustomFileDialog class.

Comment: I am now able to reproduce the problem with very simple code: QFileDialog dialog(nullptr);
    dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog, true); So, it may not have anything to do with the custom dialog, but rather, the setting of QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog flag.

Comment: It works fine in my Windows10 Qt5.15.2

Comment: It is still failing with Qt6 on Windows 11